# How to prevent recursive limit in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I need some help please,I'm having problem with the SP,how can I prevent this not to get recursive limit SQL ERROR(1456).Is there a way to change this SP not to use recursive...what I'm trying to achieve is to sum to all the amount in my left subtree on a given parentid...for example I have parentid 5,so my left is 7 so I want to sum all his amount on his subtree it's(22,500)if I'm not wrong.

Thank you in advance.

I have this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `mytree` (
    `parentid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `memberid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `position` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `ck1tree` (`memberid`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ck2tree` (`parentid`, `position`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

and here is my data in the table mytree

```
INSERT INTO `mytree` (`parentid`, `memberid`, `position`, `amount`) VALUES
    (8, 27, 'R', 0.00),
    (8, 28, 'L', 0.00),
    (24, 26, 'R', 0.00),
    (0, 1, '', 5500.00),
    (24, 25, 'L', 0.00),
    (21, 24, 'L', 500.00),
    (21, 23, 'R', 0.00),
    (18, 20, 'R', 1500.00),
    (18, 19, 'L', 0.00),
    (15, 18, 'R', 2000.00),
    (15, 17, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 16, 'L', 0.00),
    (13, 15, 'R', 2500.00),
    (12, 14, 'R', 0.00),
    (12, 13, 'L', 3000.00),
    (10, 12, 'R', 3500.00),
    (10, 11, 'L', 0.00),
    (7, 10, 'R', 4000.00),
    (7, 9, 'L', 0.00),
    (5, 8, 'R', 500.00),
    (5, 7, 'L', 4500.00),
    (1, 6, 'R', 0.00),
    (1, 5, 'L', 5500.00),
    (20, 22, 'R', 0.00),
    (20, 21, 'L', 1000.00);






CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sum_left_amount`(IN `p_memid` INT, OUT `tot_left_amount` DECIMAL(10,2))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
   DECLARE a decimal(10,2);
    DECLARE m int;
    DECLARE s decimal(10,2);

    select memberid, amount into m, a from mytree
    where parentid = p_memid and position = 'L';

    call sum_left_amount(m,s);
    set tot_left_amount = a + s;

END
```

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't even have a condition when to stop. I think it would be better if you explain to us, what you're actually trying to do. I have a feeling, that it's not a recursive procedure, what you need.

Comment: Okay I will edit my post,I will add some data and table schema.

Comment: @fancyPants,I edited now my post.